# Is there a Python GDTF module?

Tags: python, module

Is there a GDTF (parsing) module for python? GDTF meaning the open standard https://gdtf-share.com/help/en/help/gdtf_builder/key_dataformat.html
I'm searching for a module to easily work with the format.

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps - https://pypi.org/project/pygdtf/#description
I tried to install by `pip3 install pygdtf` but `import pygdtf` is failing.

Comment: Same issue here, cannot import it, will try it with python 2.7 (out of support, I know) EDIT: nope python 2.7 won't work either, sent him an E-Mail

Answer (score 0):

The pygdtf library works, new home is at https://github.com/open-stage/python-gdtf , besides the parser it contains many utilities.

To install, run:

```
python -m pip install https://codeload.github.com/open-stage/python-gdtf/zip/refs/heads/master
```

To use it, see example:

```
import pygdtf
gdtf_fixture = pygdtf.FixtureType("gdtf_file.gdtf")
```